# Question about Linear Diophantine Equation.

Tags: number-theory

A Linear Diophantine Equation is of the following form: $Ax+By+C=0$, where $\gcd(A,B)=d$ and $A=da,B=db$.
If $(x_1,y_1)$ and $(x_2,y_2)$ are two solutions of the equation, then $b \textrm{ $|$ } (x_1−x_2) \Longrightarrow (x_1−x_2)=tb$.
But how is it possible? Can anyone explain me it with better clarification?.

Answer (score 1):

Two solutions are $(x_1, y_1)$ and $(x_2, y_2)$, which means that:
$$
Ax_1 + By_1 + C = 0 \\
Ax_2 + By_2 + C = 0 \\
\implies Ax_1 + By_1 + C = Ax_2 + By_2 + C \\
\implies Ax_1 - Ax_2 = By_2 - By_1 \\
\implies A(x_1 - x_2) = B(y_2 - y_1) \\
\implies da(x_1 - x_2) = db(y_2 - y_1) \\
\implies a(x_1 - x_2) = b(y_2 - y_1)
$$
Now $b \mid a(x_1 - x_2)$, but since $\gcd(a, b) = 1$ (remember we took the GCD of $A$ and $B$ before this), we can say that $b \mid x_1 - x_2$ or in other words, $x_1 - x_2$ is an integer multiple of $b$.